# Google Fiber, how did they implement their walkthrough page?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, user-interface

http://fiber.google.com/how/

Is that all HTML5 canvas animation? Flash?  I have a hard time telling. Thanks!

[image: screenie]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not flash, and it is a combination of images and clever javascript.

EDIT: Oh and of course HTML and CSS.

Comment: Of course it always ends up being simpler than i thought.  I see now how they have a single image that represents that blue line, and they just keep revealing more and more of it as you scroll down.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of HTML5 like this http://atari.com/arcade/